# Combining two different result set into a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Two different queries, produce two different result set.

Query 1:

```
Select a.customer_name, b.salary, c.manager_name 
  from 
table123 a 
left join table456 b on a.id=b.id
left join table789 c on a.id=c.id
```

Query2:

```
Select  d.prty_id, e.party_val, f.prty_nme
from
table111 d 
Left join table222 e on d.id=e.id
Left join table333 f on d.id=f.id
```

Now I have to write one single query, which  will merge this above two query's result set and display one single result set.
Can anyone please help me on this.

Output value I need to insert in a new table whose column will be like below:

```
customer_name  salary  manager_name  prty_id   party_val   prty_nme
```

Comment: are those columns mutually competent in data types within their order of appearance( eg. `a.customer_name` & `d.prty_id` and so on ... ) ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by `merge`. You probably want `UNION`, but a `JOIN` could be an option depending on your requirement.

Comment: This is not clear. "combine" & "merge" mean nothing in particular. Clearly & fully say how the result is a function of those queries or the original tables. Give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: For more clarification I have edited my question. I have added like how I need the ouput structure. Please check it once

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The question is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

According to your expected result, you can use `UNION`  or `UNION ALL`.

The Oracle `UNION` operator is used to combine the result sets of 2 or more Oracle SELECT statements. It removes duplicate rows between the various SELECT statements.

The Oracle `UNION ALL` operator is used to combine the result sets of 2 or more SELECT statements. It returns all rows from the query and it does not remove duplicate rows between the various SELECT statements.

```
Select con1,... , coln
from tab1
where...

union 

Select con1,... , coln
from tab2
where...
```

- Just make sure your data types match up.